# Versionado semántico ¿versión mínima en producción?

Tags: ingenieria-del-software

En concreto me preocupa llegar a la versión 1.0.0 en un proyecto, y más allá... sin tenerlo listo para producción. Librerías y proyectos sencillos los libero como 1.0.0 llegado el caso.

Estoy revisando semver en: https://semver.org/lang/es/

Se que hay librerías con versiones como `0.2.1` que se distribuyen y usan en producción, no estoy seguro de si usan versionado semántico y si lo hace correctamente, o lo hago yo, realmente... Encuentro "recomendaciones", por lo que al final depende de cada cuál.

Entonces, no tengo claro si cuando hemos desarrollado "algo" que puede usarse en producción hay que "saltar" a la versión 1.0.0, o sería recomendable (yo lo hago) y si alcanzada la versión 1.0.0 en un desarrollo esta debería ser una versión "lista" para producción.

No me queda claro tampoco si los números de versión se pueden relacionar con el "estado" en el desarrollo de un proyecto o esto depende de cada desarrollador / desarrollo, más allá de usar `X.Y.Z` para ir incrementando las versiones. Aquí se dice algo al respecto: https://semver.org/lang/es/#spec-item-1:

> El software que use Versionado Semántico DEBE declarar una API
> pública. Esta API puede ser declarada en el código mismo o existir en
> documentación estricta. De cualquier manera, debería ser precisa y
> completa.

Según entiendo, debemos seguir `X.Y.Z` para el versionado pero como lo usamos depende un poco de nosotros mismos y debemos indicarlo, para lo que habla en todo momento en la página de API pública, no se si se refiere a un API Rest o usa API para una documentación de proyecto en general...

Comment: excelente pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La versión minima en producción debe ser la 1.0.0 y los motivos son los siguientes:

Primero, en el propio enlace que aportas https://semver.org/lang/es/ :

> 4. La versión major en cero (0.y.z) es para desarrollo inicial. Cualquier cosa puede cambiar en cualquier momento. El API pública no
>    debiera ser considerada estable.
> 5. La versión 1.0.0 define el API pública. La forma en que el número de versión es incrementado después de este release depende de esta API
>    pública y de cómo esta cambia.

Y podemos llegar a la misma conclusión usando la lógica:

Si creas una API y la haces pública, has de indicar de algún modo el estado de la misma y la compatibilidad. El primer número indica la retrocompatibilidad. Puesto que no hay una versión anterior (estamos publicando la primera versión) este número debe ser lo más bajo posible.

Tenemos dos opciones, 1 y 0 (ya que nos gusta empezar las listas en 0, contemplemos esta opción). Pero la versión inicial no puede ser la 0.0.0 porque nos impediría publicar versiones preliminares (alfa o beta) usando *semver*. Y la primera versión pública no puede ser 0.1.0 porque eso indicaría versiones menores previas que no eran realmente la primera versión en producción (perderíamos la semántica). Por tanto, la única opción es poner un 1 como *major*.

Como nota final, el API pública puede ser cualquier cosa: una librería que usas en tus projectos (JQuery por ejemplo está en la versión 3.5.1), una API REST, un lenguaje de programación (Python está en la versión 3.9.0, anteriormente estaba en la 3.8.6), un protocolo de comunicación (Bluetooth no usa semver, pero la versión 5.8 es la actual)... API es Interfaz Pública de Aplicaciones.